# Any way to collect payment after order submit?

Tags: magento2, payment

Is there any way for customers to submit an order detailing what they want, not requiring payment during checkout, but then paying AFTER they submit the order?

The reason is because we want to handle scenarios where if customer negotiates a different price, we can figure a final price, edit the order accordingly, and have them pay afterward.

If there's no built-in way to do this in vanilla Magento 2, is there an extension for this?

Comment: Do you find the solution?If yes please share here because i am searching for the same

Comment: @SnehaPanchal it's been a long time and I forgot :( I think we used some third-party payment solution (Braintree?) to handle orders / payments